# Advantage Database Server 10 error 5211 - There is an error converting Unicode string

Tags: delphi, unicode, delphi-2009, advantage-database-server

I'm converting a D7 app into D2009 and I've faced an issue with the Advantage Database Server (Local). Whenever I include non-parameterized Turkish characters in queries I get the error

```
[iAnywhere Solutions][Advantage SQL][ASA] 
Error 5211: There is an error converting Unicode string to or from code page string.
Some Unicode characters cannot be converted to code page characters.
```

I've tried using ansistrings in the command, like in;

```
AdsQuery1.SQL.Text:=AnsiString('SELECT something FROM sometable WHERE somefield=''somelocalçharaçterş'' ');
```

But to no avail. I've also set AdsConnection's AdsCollation values to ANSI, OEM, TURKISH-1254 but the outcome was the same. Any ideas?

Comment: It seems to me that since the problem only happens when you use *non-parameterized queries* that the solution would be pretty obvious: use *parameterized* queries. No? :)

Comment: True, but that would be extremely time consuming. I was looking for some kind of tweaking on AdsConnection's part or some sort...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you take a look of the adscollate.adt that is in the same directory of the adslocal32.dll?

According to the help file, a possible cause of the problem is that an older version of the adscollate.adt is loaded by the server. The 10.0 version of the adscollate.adt has some additional columns, one of them being the "UnicodeLocale".

What is the ANSI/OEM setting in the adslocal.cfg?

What is the result if you run this "SELECT ::stmt.collation FROM system.iota"?